# What does “espantado de sí propio” mean in the poem “A buen juez, mejor testigo”?

Tags: traducción, poesía

The phrase in question appears near the end of the poem. A miracle affects the two protagonists so intensely that they both immediately decide to abandon the world and enter the religious life.

> Las vanidades del mundo
> renunció allí mismo Inés,
> y espantado de sí propio,
> Diego Martínez también.

I'm not sure how to interpret *espantado de sí propio*, as this usage of *de sí propio* appears to be antiquated or poetic. Possibilities that occur to me are "appalled at himself," "terrified by his own actions," and "fearing for his own life."

Comment: Mirando en [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=32&smoothing=2&content=s%C3%AD+mismo%2Cs%C3%AD+propio&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cs%C3%AD%20mismo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cs%C3%AD%20propio%3B%2Cc0), _sí propio_ parece un equivalente culto a _sí mismo_ que cayó en desuso. Yo no recuerdo haberlo visto antes (pero disto mucho de ser experto en ningún idioma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the wording is poetic. "Espantado de sí propio" literally means "spooked by his own self" and it most probably refers to being terrified by his own actions or past life as you said.